# std::filesystem "root_name" definition broken on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17, boost-filesystem

I have the feeling the C++ filesystem standard is broken on windows. It is heavily based on Boost.filesystem and I just found a serious issue there which (likely) also exists in std::filesystem: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/99

The essence is the definition of "root_name" and "root_directory":

> root-name(optional): identifies the root on a filesystem with multiple roots (such as "C:" or "//myserver"). In case of ambiguity, the longest sequence of characters that forms a valid root-name is treated as the root-name. The standard library may define additional root-names besides the ones understood by the OS API.
>
> root-directory(optional): a directory separator that, if present, marks this path as absolute. If it is missing (and the first element other than the root name is a file name), then the path is relative and requires another path as the starting location to resolve to a file name.

This requires e.g. "C:\foo\bar.txt" to be decomposed into:

- root_name: "C:"
- root_directory: "\" or "/" (does this even make sense?)
- directory: "foo"
- file_name "bar.txt"

The problem now: The first part of this path is not a path, at least not the original one. This comes from the interpretation on windows:

- "C:\" is the drive "C"
- "C:" is the current working directory on the drive "C"

Minor: How should "\foo\bar.txt" be interpreted on windows according to the above? You have a "root_directory" (which is strangely not a directory but a directory *separator*) but no "root_name" hence the path cannot be absolute and so you don't have a "root_directory" either. sigh.

So from this I feel that "root_name" and "root_directory" cannot be decomposed (on windows). In "C:\foo" you'll have "C:\" and in "C:foo" you'll have "C:". Or to keep the (strangely defined) "root_directory" you'd need to set decompose "C:\foo" into "C:\", "\" and "foo" and struggle with the latter: Is that an absolute path? Actually it is: "The folder 'foo' in the current working directory on drive C", quite absolute, isn't it?

But well you could say "absolute==independent of current working dir" then the "root_directory" makes sense: It would be "\" for "C:\foo" and empty for "C:foo".

So question: Is the standard wrong in defining "C:" as the "root_name" instead of "C:\" in paths like "C:\foo" or is it simply invalid usage to iterate over components of a path expecting the prefix sums to be "valid"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation of the Windows filesystem is incorrect. The directory `C:\` is the root directory of the "C" drive, not "the drive 'C'". This is distinct from `C:`, which is the current directory of the "C" drive. Just try using the Windows shell and see how `C:<stuff>` behaves relative to `C:\<stuff>`. Both will access stuff on that drive, but both will do so starting from different directories.

Think of it in these terms on Windows:

- `C:` means "Go to the current directory of the C drive".
- `\` at the start of a path (after any root names) means "Go to the root directory of the current drive".
- `foo\` means "Go into the directory called 'foo' within whatever directory we are currently in".
- `bar.txt` means "The file named 'bar.txt' in whatever directory we are currently in."

Therefore, `C:\foo\bar.txt"` means: Go to the current directory of the C drive, then go to the root directory of C, then go into the 'foo' directory of the root directory of C, then access the file 'bar.txt' in the 'foo' directory of the root directory of C.

Similarly, `C:foo\bar.txt` means: Go to the current directory of the C drive, then go into the 'foo' directory of the current directory of C, then access the file 'bar.txt' in the 'foo' directory of the current directory of C.

This is how Windows paths work. This is what it means to type those things in the Windows shell. And thus, this is how Boost/std filesystem paths were designed to work.

> But well you could say "absolute==independent of current working dir"

But that's not how std filesystem defines [the concept of "absolute path"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/filesystems#fs.def.absolute.path):

> **Absolute Path** A path that unambiguously identifies the location of a file without reference to an additional starting location. The elements of a path that determine if it is absolute are operating system dependent.

So "relative" and "absolute" are implementation-dependent. In Windows, a path is not absolute unless it contains *both* a root-name and a root-directory. In the Windows filesystem implementation, `path("\foo\bar.txt").is_absolute()` will be false.

Comment: Good explanation thanks. This is a major pitfall that even lead to (at least) 1 bug in boost... Just a note: I think my interpretation of absolute path still catches the essence although it is a bit less general.

Comment: The volume device name is "C:",  not "C", i.e. we open the volume as "\\.\C:" or "\\?\C:" (or as "\??\C:" in NT), which links to an enumerated volume such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2".  Windows begins by classifying a path into one of 8 [`RTL_PATH_TYPE`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/releases/0.4.11/sdk/include/ndk/rtltypes.h#L462) categories via [`RtlDetermineDosPathNameType_Ustr`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/releases/0.4.11/sdk/lib/rtl/path.c#L54).

Comment: Note also that "C:\" is absolute but not fully qualified as a path across the whole system, i.e. it won't necessarily refer to the same device if passed to another process. The global "C:" object link can be shadowed in a logon session's local devices. We need "\\?\Global\C:\" for it to be fully qualified across logon sessions.

Comment: [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) documents that _Each process has a single current directory that consists of two parts_ - _A disk designator that is either a drive letter followed by a colon, or a server name followed by a share name_ and _A directory on the disk designator_ .

Comment: @ridilculous: And they also have a per-drive current directory. Go to a command line, go to `C:`, change to some directory in there, go to `D:`, change to a directory in there, then type `C:` again. It remembers what directory you were last in on that drive.

Comment: @NicolBolas Absolutely. But only the shell has this and the console is a special process with a custom behavior. No other process from ms natively supports this afaik (not even windows explorer). It can be easily tested with some [GS]etCurrentDirectory invocations (not on godbolt unfortunately but i can provide code). I don't understand why the windows shell should be representative for the windows filesystem; it's just one interface.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `root_path`, see *[Filesystem TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf) § 8.4.9, path decomposition*:

> `path root_path() const;`
>
> Returns: `root_name()` `/` `root_directory()`

Here's how Microsoft [defines it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem?view=vs-2017):

> Common to both systems is the structure imposed on a pathname once you
>   get past the root name. For the pathname `c:/abc/xyz/def.ext`:
>
> - The root name is `c:`.
> - The root directory is `/`.
> - **The root path is `c:/`.**
> - The relative path is `abc/xyz/def.ext`.
> - The parent path is `c:/abc/xyz`.
> - The filename is `def.ext`.
> - The stem is `def`.
> - The extension is `.ext`.

So a truly absolute path would begin with `root_name` + `root_directory`, or `root_path`.

See also [`system_complete(p)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem-functions?view=vs-2017#system_complete) for resolving current directory on other drives:

> *Effects:* Composes an absolute path from `p`, using the same rules used by the operating system to resolve a path passed as the filename argument to standard library open functions.
>
> [*Example:* For POSIX based operating systems, `system_complete(p)` has the same semantics as `absolute(p, current_path()).`
>
> For Windows based operating systems, `system_complete(p)` has the same semantics as
>   `absolute(p, current_path())` if `p.is_absolute() || !p.has_root_name()` or `p` and
>   base have the same `root_name()`. Otherwise it acts like `absolute(p, cwd)` is the current directory for the `p.root_name()` drive. This will be the current directory for that drive the last time it was set, and thus may be residue left over from a prior program run by the command processor. Although these semantics are useful, they may be surprising. *—end example*]

Comment: It should be noted that the [standard defines](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/filesystems#fs.path.decompose-3) `root_path` to be `root_­name() / root_­directory()`, always. Also, `system_complete` is *not* part of the standard filesystem API.